# viewの埋め込みコードで発生する例外を確認する方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Ruby on Rails 3.2.13 
Rspec 2.14.0

こんにちは。

これまでまともにテストを書いていなかったのですが、さすがにまずいと思いRspecの勉強を始めました。

タイトルの通り、viewの中の埋め込みコードで結構な頻度で例外が発生するので、これを確認するためのテストを書きたいと思い、controllerのテストで

```
it 'returns status 200' do
  get :show, {:id => user.id}
  expect(response).to be_success
end
```

としてみたところ、ブラウザ上では例外500が出ているのにも拘らず成功してしまいます。

こういった場合はどのようにテストを書くと良いのでしょうか？初歩的な質問で恐縮なのですが、Googleで調べてもなかなか欲しい情報が出てこず困っています。

どうかみなさんのお力をお貸しください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ControllerのテストなのでデフォルトではViewをレンダリングしません。

もし、View（ERB）の中でエラーが発生しているとControllerのテストはパスして、ブラウザで開くとエラー、という可能性があります。

この予想が当たっているのであれば、解決方法は二つぐらいあるかなと思います。

#### 解決策1

Controller specでviewをレンダリングし、responseの内容を検証する。

以下のページが参考になりそうです。

https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-1/docs/controller-specs/render-views

#### 解決策2

Controller specではなくFeature specを書く。

Feature specであればブラウザ上の操作をかなりリアルにシミュレートできるので、テストはパスしてブラウザではエラーになる、という可能性が低くなります。

Feature specについては僕がQiitaに書いたこの記事が参考になるかもしれません。

http://qiita.com/jnchito/items/607f956263c38a5fec24

どちらの解決策がオススメかと言えば、僕は後者のFeature specをオススメします。  
Controller specも全く書かないわけではないですが、僕の場合、書く頻度としてはModel specとFeature specの方が多いです。

なお、手前味噌になりますが、これからRSpecの勉強をするのであれば僕が翻訳した電子書籍 **「Everyday Rails - RSpecによるRailsテスト入門」** を読んでもらうことをオススメします。

https://leanpub.com/everydayrailsrspec-jp

RSpec 3系とRSpec 2系の2種類のファイル（電子書籍）をダウンロードすることができるので、RSpec 2系を使っていても大丈夫です。

#### それでも解決できない場合

ブラウザで発生しているエラーの詳しい内容を質問に追記してください。  
`log/development.log`に出力されているエラーのスタックトレースをコピーしてもらうのが一番よいと思います。